# Does Appium allow to automate Chrome on real iOS device?

Tags: ios, automation, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation, appium

I am interested in tool which could automate web apps on real iOS devices using some programming language. Does Appium tool allow to automate Google Chrome browser on real iOS device?

Answer (score 3):

Appium Supports automation of mobile WebApps through mobile safari only. No support for Chrome yet for iOS although for Android chrome is supported.

Comment: is Safari browser supported on android?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official introduction](https://github.com/liontree/appium/blob/master/docs/hybrid.md), when executing against a real device appium is unable to access the web view directly. Therefore the connection has to be established through the USB lead. To establish this connection we use the [ios-webkit-debugger-proxy](https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy).